# Array of size 1 vs. pointer to struct

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

Let's say I have a function which takes an array of structs, defined like so:

```
void Foo(struct MyStruct *s, int count) {
    for (int i = 0; i < count; ++i) {
        // Do something with s[i]
    }
}
```

Are these following two snippets guaranteed to behave the same way?

```
struct MyStruct s;
s.x = 0;
s.y = 0;
Foo(&s, 1);
```

vs.

```
struct MyStruct s[1]; // stack-allocated array of size 1
s[0].x = 0;
s[0].y = 0;
Foo(s, 1);
```

Comment: https://godbolt.org/g/3iq38U you can see they generated same machine code

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The answer is yes, they are effectively the same. First, arrays are passed as pointer to its first element, when used in function arguments. Actually, all objects in C can be treated as a array of one element of that type in terms of storage.

Answer (score 3):

Yes. Both options are stack-allocated and create exactly one 'instance' of `struct MyStruct`. Your compiler is expected to output the same machine code for both options. See [this link](http://gribblelab.org/CBootcamp/7_Memory_Stack_vs_Heap.html) (C) and [this link](http://people.eecs.ku.edu/~miller/Courses/JavaToC++/StackAllocatedArrays.html) (C++) for more details.

Comment: The op was asking about C, the link is about C++ and Java.

Comment: Not exactly... it explains how stack allocation works in C++ and how it relates to Java - even though it compares C++ to Java, it explains how stack allocation works. I just added another link which explains stack allocation for pure C as well.

Answer (score 3):

They are identical; proof - I compiled and saved the assembly code generated by both MSVC 2015 and GCC 4.9.3 for these two code samples:

```
// Case 1: Pass by reference to single struct
typedef struct _mystruct
{
    int x;
    int y;
} mystruct;

void foo(mystruct *s, int count)
{
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        (*(s + i)).x = 5; 
        (*(s + i)).y = 7;
    }
}

int main()
{
    mystruct ps;

    //mystruct as[1];
    

    foo(&ps, 1);
    //foo(as, 1);
    return 0;
}
```

I note that the operations in `foo` are random and not really relevant to the test; they are just to prevent the compiler from optimizing out the method.

```
// Case 2: 1-length array
typedef struct _mystruct
{
    int x;
    int y;
} mystruct;

void foo(mystruct *s, int count)
{
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        (*(s + i)).x = 5; 
        (*(s + i)).y = 7;
    }
}

int main()
{
    //mystruct ps;

    mystruct as[1];
    

    //foo(&ps, 1);
    foo(as, 1);
    return 0;
}
```

In the generated assembly files, on GCC they are exactly identical, and in MSVC, literally the only differences are:

1. The variable names in the comments (`s` vs `as`)
2. The line numbers referenced (since different ones are uncommented in each version).

Therefore, it is safe to assume that these two methods are identical.